# MySQL structure for component stock/order system

Tags: php, mysql, excel, stock

I am making a component order system for my electronics manufacturing company.
We have used Excel up until now, but it is starting to get really complex and we see that php/mysql could do this rather trivially. I am an electronics guy with some programming experience so bear with me.

I have started with making a component library as you can see in picture 1.

And this is working fine. The problem appears when I want to mimic this spreadsheet (picture 2).

Here I add stock for each purchased item when there is a new order. A new column is made for each time. In this picture, 3 orders are made for 6000 of CC1110F32RHHR. How would one go on for solving this using MySQL? Doesn't seem like a good solution to add a new column here.

Picture 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOhx.jpg 
Picture 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCRgR.jpg

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the quick feedback. I can see that I have not explained this issue well enough.
In the excel sheet (picture2) new stock is added to each manufacturer part number when I click a button. I would like to make the same view in PHP. The data does not have to be structured this way.

The problem I am facing is that I have hundreds of manufacturer part numbers and I want to store new info on each of them regularly(order date, stock bought that day). But the only way to do this as I see it to have a separate column for each of them. There must be another way?

**EDIT2:**

Tried to make an example in text below.
If you see here, when I do it like this I can only make one order before I cannot put anymore information in it(without adding new columns named orderid2 etc..). So clearly this is not the right way of structuring the table. In my different tables mpn is the unique identifier so I always can get more info on a selected mpn from the component library.

```
mpn        date        orderedstock      orderid

part1      1.1.15      1500              1
part2
part3      1.1.15      750               1
part4
part5
...
part274
```

Comment: Would you add into the question the database schema you are working on? I assume you're looking for a SQL query, would you describe that query in your question? What does the spreadsheet do that you want to do in a database? "How to solve it" is a bit vague, IMO.

Comment: (We tend to encourage people to show us what they have tried here also. You've got a database design, but if you can show us a `SELECT` statement - even an unfinished one that you are stuck on - that will help us see what the problem is that you're facing).

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. If data is sensitive, instead provide plausible dummy data.

Comment: Where is picture 3? Also, it is not good to link to pictures outside of SO. Please include all relevant info within the table. Your data is not graphic in nature, so create text!

Comment: @luksch Added a comma, was referring to picture 2.

<br>Thanks for the comments everyone. Actually the question is general, as i'm trying to find a way to store new info on a row without sorting my manufacturer part numbers in columns. So I don't have a query to show, as this is a question about how to structure the table.

Comment: You already have your components as one table by the looks of things. Create a separate table of purchase orders and then a third table of ordered components which has the component ID and purchase order ID as foreign keys

Comment: @barrowc Thanks. This was what I was after, but apparently I did not formulate my question very good. Would've marked this as correct answer if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Adding columns is changing the database schema. Those operations are not meant usually for normal data input. Relational databases are optimized for tabular data with a fixed table structure.

So you should organize your data in a way that makes new data appear in new rows, not new columns.

Your data seems very structured, so a relational approach seems a good choice. If you have a lot of flexibility in the fields you may want to look into NoSQL solutions which generally focus on efficient column wise aggregation/Queries.

Sorry that this is a rather general answer, but your question is not specific enough to go into detail.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Tried to rephrase some of the question to make it more understandable.